# History of jobs in JasperServer

Tags: jasperserver

Where I can find history of ended scheduled jobs in JasperServer? I have access to postre repository, but I can't find it.
I found only table jireportjob where I can find current jobs.

Comment: I assume they are deleted from DB. The REST API also does return the current jobs only. Reocurring jobs are invoked via triggers in qrtz_triggers table.

Comment: Do you know which script is responsible for the activities on the database? Maybe there is chance to modify it to not delete it or insert finished jobs to other table. I'm using community edition 7.2

Comment: I assume that's done by Spring & hibernate. You could create a postgres BEFORE DELETE trigger to back it up to your table.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the database and the jaspersoft database, then this should get you started.

```sql
SELECT
      j."label"                     AS JobName
    , CASE
        WHEN je.event_text LIKE '%report.scheduling.error.upload.to.ftp.server%'
            THEN 'Report Upload To FTP Server Error'
        WHEN je.event_text LIKE '%report.scheduling.error%'
            THEN 'Report Generic Scheduling Error'
        WHEN je.event_text LIKE '%error.generating.report%'
            THEN 'Report Generation Error'
        ELSE 'Other Error'
      END                           AS PotentialCause
    , je.*
FROM      jasperserver.public.jilogevent je
LEFT JOIN jasperserver.public.jireportjob j ON je.resource_uri  = j.report_unit_uri
ORDER BY occurrence_date DESC
;
```